# Font Face in wordpress is not working in IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using a wordpress, i use the Font Face tag in css file for custom fonts, it is working in all browser but not in IE please help me

Thanks

Comment: Did you check with IE web developer toolbar?

Comment: sir, i have check the other example of font face in IE these are finely working but in my case it is not working

Comment: Check using IE Web Developer Toolbar if its IE8+

Comment: Maybe it would be easier for you to try http://www.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score 1):

IE8 and lower don't support @font-face if your font is not in .EOT file format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming IE has a developer tool like Firefox and Chrome, hit F12 and select the CSS tab. Maybe your style is being overwritten somewhere or maybe IE is just a POC (I suspect the latter).

Comment: Yes... IE 8+ have Web Developer Toolbar.

Comment: I check with the help of developer tool in IE the font family:'MyriadProRegular', serif; is displaying but not working

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said. @font-face is a CSS3 attribute not supported by most older browsers. I would suggest using something like Font Squirrel to make it work with older browsers.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Also more about @font-face

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule